# Splitting pandas DF into equal chunks based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a sample `df` which I am trying to `create chunks` where `a given column value is spread equally (almost) among the chunks`.

For example, consider the DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["apple",1],["mango",20],["mango",20],["mango",31],["apple",17],
                  ["apple",17],["mango",17],["mango",17],["mango",17],["mango",17],["mango",17],["mango",17],["mango",17],
                   ["apple",17],["mango",17],["mango",17],["apple",17]
                  ])
df.columns = ["fruit", "count"]
df
```

if I want to create `2 chunks` of this `df` where the value for `fruit column =apple` gets split equally among the  2 chunks.

my current version, first create separate Dfs for `mango and apple` and then create the splits and concat corresponding splits.

Code:

```
df_apple = df.loc[df["fruit"]=="apple"]
df_apple_splits = np.array_split(df_apple,2)
df_mango = df.loc[df["fruit"]=="mango"]
df_mango_splits = np.array_split(df_mango,2)

df_split1 = pd.concat([df_apple_splits[0],df_mango_splits[0]])
df_split2 = pd.concat([df_apple_splits[1],df_mango_splits[1]])
```

But is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try iterating over a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on fruit, [`array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) into 2 DataFrames, then [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to transpose the list of lists of DataFrames, then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to create a list of DataFrames (which can be unpacked into two variables):

```
df_split1, df_split2 = [
    pd.concat(lst) for lst in
    zip(*[np.array_split(v, 2) for _, v in df.groupby('fruit')])
]
```

`df_split1`:

```
   fruit  count
0  apple      1
4  apple     17
5  apple     17
1  mango     20
2  mango     20
3  mango     31
6  mango     17
7  mango     17
8  mango     17
```

`df_split2`:

```
    fruit  count
13  apple     17
16  apple     17
9   mango     17
10  mango     17
11  mango     17
12  mango     17
14  mango     17
15  mango     17
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'fruit': ['apple', 'mango', 'mango', 'mango', 'apple',
              'apple', 'mango', 'mango', 'mango', 'mango',
              'mango', 'mango', 'mango', 'apple', 'mango',
              'mango', 'apple'],
    'count': [1, 20, 20, 31, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17,
              17, 17, 17, 17]
})
```